# Reference not updated in android

Tags: java, android, baseadapter

So in pseudocode it's something like this.

```
class Example {
    private ExampleState state;
    private List<ExampleState> states;
    public Example() {
        state = new ExampleState(parameters);
        CustomAdapter = new CustomAdapter(context, state);
    }

    public someMethod() {
        state = states.get(states.size() - 1);  
        cellAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
    }

}

class CustomAdapter {
    protected ExampleState state; // that's where data is

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ExampleState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

After someMethod the CustomAdapter state field stays the same.
As I think of it At first I'm creating the object ExampleState in Example constructor. Then I'm passing the reference to it to adapter. Then I'm changing the object to reference to another object.

So before someMethod the id of field "state" in Example and in CustomAdapter was the same. And after it the one in Example is new and one in CustomAdapter is old one.
Why is reference is not updated?

Comment: "jandroid" -- not a bad way to say "Java on Android," I suppose!

Comment: Sorry. Its should be "state" in this example, not currentState. I've changed it already. So it's the same entity.

Jandroid is just my misprint, soryy :)

Comment: Sorry. In real code of course it's all done in right way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an example of Java being pass-by-value

In this method

```
public someMethod() {
    state = states.get(states.size() - 1);  
    cellAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); 
}
```

You change the reference stored in `state`.

However, in

```
class CustomAdapter {
    protected ExampleState state; // that's where data is

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ExampleState state) {
        this.state = state;
    }
}
```

In the constructor, you were passed a copy of the value of the `ExampleState` reference. This is the original (old) value. Changing that reference in the `Example` object doesn't affect the `CustomAdapter.state` reference.

You should instead pass the `Example` object to the `CustomAdapter` constructor and store and always retrieve its `state` reference.

Comment: Ok, I got that. I've read about that java is passes objects as reference and it passes the references by value.

Now it makes sense.